# Cant import gspread when using python 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-import, gspread

I downloaded gspread the other day using pip. I manage to import it into a python file and run the file when using python 2.7.6 but when using python 3.4.3 it returns error *no module named gspread*. I did see that when I go to where gspread is installed its under 2.7.6 meanwhile I have discord api under 3.4.3. Anything I can do to get gspread to work with python3? Thank you!

I dont have problem with importing anymore but when running very simple code I get an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
        sheet = client.open('Test').sheet1
      File "/home/marbj634/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 82, in open
feed = self.get_spreadsheets_feed()
      File "/home/marbj634/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 155, in get_spreadsheets_feed
r = self.session.get(url)
      File "/home/marbj634/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 73, in get
return self.request('GET', url, params=params, **kwargs)
      File "/home/marbj634/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 65, in request
response = func(url, data=data, params=params, headers=request_headers, files=files, json=json)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 467, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'
```

My code is only:

```
    import gspread
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
    import pprint

    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)

    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()

    sheet = client.open('Test').sheet1

    values = sheet.get_all_values()

    pp.pprint(values)
```

Comment: Did you use the right version of pip? There's pip and pip3.

Comment: Is it possible to just copy the gspread folders from python2.7 to python3.4?

Comment: I used pip, is pip3 for python3?

Comment: There is a separate version of pip for Python 3. install `python3-pip` and then reinstall gspread with `pip3 install gspread`

Comment: It seems to be working, but I seem to need to upgrade request, do I do that with pip3 aswell?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have used wrong version of pip. To install packages for Python3, you must use `pip3`. To install gspread, simply use `pip3 install gspread`.

In case you are missing pip3, you can install it using this command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: @ifconfig I'd imagine he does. Majority of the time, where's Python there's pip.

Comment: Not all of the time. Some debian images I have seen come with just python, and not pip.

Comment: I added more information in my question, the import is now solved but when running on 3.4.3 I get an error as shown above which I dont get on 2.7.6